# Time Machine backup of legacy filevault encrypted homedir?

Tags: macos, time-machine, filevault

I have recently upgraded from Snow Leopard to Mountain Lion. Given that I don't have a lot of space left on disk, it was not feasible to migrate from Filevault to Filevault 2. 
I have just noticed today that Time Machine seems to ignore my homedir sparsebundle in its backups. On Snow Leopard, it would back it up when I logged out. Now it does not do that anymore, and so I don't have any backup of my homedir since the migration to Mountain Lion. Does anyone have any ideas on how this can be fixed or worked around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this on 10.8.4, but here's how I used to work around this.

1. Make a second account that exists only for you to be able to log out completely of your main account.
2. Log into the second account only.
3. Start a backup so that the legacy file vault files can be backed up.

Basically, Time Machine doesn't run unless *someone* is logged in.

Comment: Ok, that sounds a bit hack-ish, but it should work... It's weird that they've changed that behavior. I'll give it a try, thanks for the answer!